# remove UIImageView from its Superview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview

In my application when the user touches the screen, I put an `UIImageView` on the screen like this:

```
- (void) drawPoint:(CGPoint) toLocation {
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(toLocation.x, toLocation.y, SIZE_X, SIZE_Y)];
    image.tag = 1;
    [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"]];
    [self.myView addSubview:image];
    [image release];
}
```

Here `MyView` is an `UIView`.

When the user has finished touching, I want to remove my `UIImageView`. I have tried this:

```
- (void) removeFromPoint:(CGPoint) location{
    UIImageView *image;
    [[image viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

or

```
- (void) removeFromPoint:(CGPoint) location{
    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[self.MyView viewWithTag:1];
    [image removeFromSuperview];
}
```

but both of them end up in EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
Do you know how can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: show us the declaration of myview property

Comment: What does the call stack look like when you get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? You can see it in GDB and it'll show you who is trying to access an object after its destruction.

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised receiving a `EXC_BAD_ACCES` in the first block: You're are sending a message to an uninitialized object in `removeFromPoint:`. Your image variable just contains some garbage, to which you can't send anything! And in your second block of code, I think you might have made a typo: `self.MyView` should be `self.myView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove uimage under the touch try this:

```
UIView * imageView = [self.myView hitTest:location withEvent:nil];
if ([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && imageView.tag == 1) {
   [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

(note I've typed it here, i haven't test that code)

If you wish to debug your code enable NSZombies and check why you gets the bad_access. (check this to learn more about NSZombieEnabled http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)

If you are going to add only one view. Then I would store it in a retained property and I would add/remove it on events like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView* marker;

@interface
@syntesize marker;

-(void) onTouchDown {
    [self.view addSubview:marker];
}

-(void) onTouchUp {
    [marker removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I want to remove my UIImageView when the user lift off the finger from the screen. It doesn't matter where my UIImageView is located. What you told my is basically exactly how I tried: UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[self.MyView viewWithTag:1]; [image removeFromSuperview];. And this doesn't worked for me.

Comment: @parkyprg, Ok so it must be something wrong with self.myView. Could you show us how you declared that property?

Answer (score 1):

The first example of removing image view is wrong.
In the second one what is POINT_TAG equal to?
Try to use tag greater then 9.
Try to debug what `UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[self.MyView viewWithTag:POINT_TAG];`
returns.

Comment: POINT_TAG is 1 - I forgot to specify it. I modified my post. And debugging that returns an UIImageView.

Comment: Try to use NSZombieEnabled YES as Piotr Czapla suggested. It will give you more info to debug.